# Laravel 5.4 npm run dev error

Tags: laravel

**FIXED:** Solution was to delete the node_modules folder and re-run npm instal, and after this everything was working.

I'm having some problems with Laravel and trying to run "npm run dev", i get this error:

```
              Asset      Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
       /js/app.js   1.18 MB       0  [emitted]  [big]  /js/app
mix-manifest.json  32 bytes          [emitted]         
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! @ dev: `node node_modules/cross-env/dist/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ dev script 'node node_modules/cross-env/dist/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the  package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node node_modules/cross-env/dist/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs 
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls 
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
```

My versions of Npm and Node is:

Npm: 4.5.0
Node: v7.8.0

And Laravel 5.4

Here is my packages.json:

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "node node_modules/cross-env/dist/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch": "node node_modules/cross-env/dist/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch-poll": "node node_modules/cross-env/dist/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --watch-poll --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "hot": "node node_modules/cross-env/dist/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "production": "node node_modules/cross-env/dist/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.15.3",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
    "cross-env": "^3.2.3",
    "jquery": "^3.1.1",
    "laravel-mix": "0.*",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "vue": "^2.1.10"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "webpack": "^2.3.3"
  }
}
```

Any solution?

Comment: Do you have `webpack.mix.js` file in your directory root?

Comment: Are you running on a windows machine? https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mix#running-mix => delete your node_modules folder and re run npm install like this: npm install --no-bin-links

Comment: I have the webpack.mix.js in my root, haven't changed anything here. Also i'm running Mac

Comment: I got it fixed, see topic.

Answer (score 0):

I did a fresh installation of laravel updated my node and npm and all worked fine,followed these steps

```
npm install
npm install cross-env -D
npm run dev
```